Dask worker running long calls
The code running on the dask worker calls asyncio.run() and proceeds to exectue a series of async calls (on the worker running event_loop) that gather data, and then run a small computation.
This works fine, both locally and when deployed on k8s.
If I have to make many calls to gather data (e.g. 66 different calls instead of the usual 1 single call) the time to go through all those calls ends up in the 3-5 minutes and this leads to different behaviours:

locally, there are no issues
on k8s, the log shows the worker received signal 9

Resources (RAM) are abundant, and there are no log lines complaining of not yielding to the event loop, which are the two reasons I am aware of that could cause the worker to be killed.
I know this isn't exactly the dask usecase, but it does run fine with LocalCluster... so I'd like to set it up in the same way on k8s.
I assumed it might be the nanny having some internal timeout set, so I tried to run the worker with --no-nanny but since I'm using n_worker=2 I get an error: "you can't use --no-nanny if you're running more than one worker process". At the moment I need to use 2 worker processes, though, so --no-nanny isn't viable for me.
What could the problem be? If it can only be the nanny, is there a way to remove the timeout on the duration of the "request" processing?

I'm not sure why it would fail with K8S and not with LocalCluster. Do you have a reproducer? If async is correctly used, I don't see why there should be any timeout. Do you see something in Scheduler logs?

The scheduler logs only mention the worker reconnecting and give no real insight. I tried with no-nanny on 1 process and it still gets killed so it's not the nanny. Sadly I don't have a small reproducing example.

Do you have more insights about why the worker is getting killed?
